# Improve Vlookup on large file

Tags: excel

I´ve a very large file that I reduced as much as possible to 3 columns and 80k rows.

I need to perform a vlookup in order to bring values from column 1 or 2 match some other spreadsheets values.

The thing is Excel doesn´t seem to support such large searches, and it stops responding - the computer has 4GB and a Quad core, and not much more running at the same time.

As far as I understand, as I´m not looking for exact matches, I should not use match-index.

The only thing I thouhgt could help but not sure about that, is dividing the file in 2-4, and asking Excel many parallel searches instead of a big one. Could this work?

What else should I try?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Sort your data and use True as the 4th VLOOKUP argument. This makes VLOOKUP use binary search rather than linear search and is lightning fast.

If you need to handle missing data you will need to use the double VLOOKUP trick, see
http://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2012/03/29/vlookup-tricks-why-2-vlookups-are-better-than-1-vlookup/